# Count number of digits in array and display them, plus multiply it by given number

Tags: c, debugging, computer-science

I have to create an array from an entered value. I also need to display array contents, which I have done and that performs to my liking. I am just having some issues trying to have the program count the amount of digits and display them "digits detected" I also need to multiply the original entered value (number) by 11 and display it at the end of my program.

**Problems I need help debugging:**
 1.) Counting and displaying how many digits was entered 
 2.) Multiplying first entered number by 11.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int number, count, mult;
int numbers[9];

    printf("Please enter a number:\n>");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    mult= number * 11;

    for(count = 4; count >= 0; count--) {

    if(number <= 0)
    numbers[count] = 0;

    numbers[count] = number % 10;
    number /= 10;

}

    for(count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    printf("Digit Value: %d\t\n", numbers[count]);

    count = 0;
    while(number!=0)
    {
            number/=10;
            ++count;
    }
    printf("Digits Detected: %d\n", number);
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How easy is it to store the entry * 11 before you do anything with it? `mult11 = number * 11;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-initialise `count` before you work out the number of digits

```
count = 0;              // <<---- add this line
while(number!=0)
{
    number/=10;
    ++count;
}
```

Your other question was multiplying the entered number by 11. You can do this before you altered it, like this

```
scanf("%d", &number);
mult11 = number * 11;
```

then you can print it wherever you like.

Comment: Thank you guys. Simple mistakes that I looked over!

Answer (score 0):

I am not from c/c++ background, but as per what I can Observe there are two things.

1. `for(count = 4; count >= 0; count--)`

You have defined `int numbers[9]`. You should initialize the count with 9 and not 4. But anyways even if you decide to use 4 its OK. 
Please note that once this loop completes its execution the value of `number` is modified as you have divided it by 10 in each iteration of the loop

2. As you use same `count` in the function you change its value in for loop as below

`for(count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    printf("Digit Value: %d\t\n", numbers[count]);`

Value of `count` is 5 [although if you accept my point 1, then you should change 5 to 9 in you for loop condition also]. 
Value of `number` has already been modified as I have described above.

This is the reason you can not see the correct number of digits.

I suggest you to calculate the number of digits while filling your array only.

Hope this helps you.